# Johnny Winter on Muddy Waters Mannish Boy?

Tags: blues, johnny-winter

I am currently listening to Johnny Winter, Muddy Waters and B.B. King.
I know, that these guys play very often together.

The last LP I was listening to was Muddy Waters - Hard Again from 1977.
The opening song is Mannish Boy, which is a rerecording from the original one from 1955.

I know that Johnny Winters was the producer of Hard again, but:
If you listen to [Mannish Boy](https://youtu.be/ZoVO9zZTJ10?list=PLB7L1iP9FUrDKwrjgcxKH8eRhVKiTBaJe&t=31) in the background someone is screaming "yeah".
Is this Johnny Winter? The sound of the voice is very similar from the live recordings of Johnny Winter, but I can't find any information if he was also performing and not only the producer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those divine screams are definitely Johnny Winters'. Sleeve notes [credit](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Muddy-Waters-Hard-Again/release/1119040) him

> Producer, Guitar, Voice [Miscellaneous Screaming] – **Johnny Winter**

You can also see on this [CD inner sleeve](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Muddy-Waters-Hard-Again/release/2859565):
[image]